# LWC Datatable: How to apply CSS to the text content?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I have a datatable in LWC. For one of the columns, I am setting the style class to `slds-icon-custom-custom9` which changes the text content of that column to white. When I hover the cursor over this column, the text becomes invisible because the background as well text is white.

Is there a way I can change the text content of a cell to be black when using `slds-icon-custom-custom9`? I tried using style through the `basic.css` file, but its style won't apply to the cell of the datatable.

If I don't use `slds-icon-custom-custom9`, how do I change the background color of the cell?

Playground link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/58/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can add another class for font color black like this

```
ele.AttributeName = 'slds-icon-custom-custom9 slds-text-color_default';
```

here is PG https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/62/edit

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However , if the column type is 'Url' it doesn't work. Any workaround around that?