# Lightning Datatable - Dynamically Hide actions for specific rows on the basis of data

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, shadow-dom

I have a lightning data table with some columns and row-actions. These row actions are configured dynamically on the basis of row data. For example, If I am fetching some Payments data into my table and if the status(column) of a particular record(row) has value 'Paid', then the Row Actions should have 'Refund', 'View Receipt', 'Send Receipt' options available

[image]

otherwise if the status is 'Failed' the Row Actions dropdown should not be visible at all :

[image]

In my case, I am able to set the criteria for Row Actions but not able to hide the dropdown icon when there are no Row Actions. It has to be done dynamically from JS but I am not able to achieve it.

Code :
paymentsTable.html :

[image]

=========================================================

paymentsTable.js:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: just change the config for the column like so `{type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.getRowActions }, }` and then in `getRowActions` you can decide what you want

Comment: I have observed that custom css doesn't work with `cellAttributes`. Can you try using standard styles instead and check? Like `slds-hide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting cellAttribute inside typeAttribute both should be separate like this

```
 typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions},cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'cssClass'} }
```

you can also directly use "slds-hide" class instead of using static resource simply use

```
cssClass:'slds-hide'
```

Instead of "hideActionButton"

Comment: Thanks for the response. The solution worked for me. Just one small thing, How can I update the text color of RowActions from Grey to dodger blue.

Comment: @GauravSharma  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305075/lwc-datatable-apply-css-in-the-text-content/305092#305092 you can try this with slds color classes if you could not find your color then you will have to upload static resource i guess